# XAMPP VM not running after Mac OS Update 11.3

Tags: macos, xampp

After I updated my MacBook OS BigSur to Version 11.3 I receive to following error message when I try to start XAMPP (VM):
Error starting „XAMPP“ stack
Details: cannot calculate MAC address: hv_vm_create unknown error -85377023

I tried different XAMPP versions (7.3.27, 7.4.16, 8.0.3) but it´s all the same.

It would be great if somebody had an idea!!!

Comment: I got the same problem. Still have not got any solution.

Comment: It also did not work after using the commend "rm -rf ~/.bitnami/stackman"